# How to set a relative soft link using $SINGULARITY_ROOTFS in the setup part of the Singularity recipe file?

Tags: symbolic-link, singularity-containers

I'm trying to create soft link in the `%setup` section of the Singularity recipe file. If the link is relative, it does not work. For example:

```
ln -s ${SINGULARITY_ROOTFS}../python2/2.7.5a ${SINGULARITY_ROOTFS}/usr/pkgs/python/2.7.5
```

It creates:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Apr 24 06:33 /tmp/build-temp-976030219/rootfs/usr/pkgs/python/2.7.5 -> /tmp/build-temp-976030219/rootfs../python2/2.7.5a
```

The `/tmp/build-temp-976030219/rootfs../python2/2.7.5a` is of course invalid path. I don't want to start getting the realpath because I could get other links on the way. How to make it work with **relative paths**? Am I not using the `${SINGULARITY_ROOTFS}` properly?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work with relative paths, give `ln` a relative path:

```
ln -s ../python2/2.7.5a ${SINGULARITY_ROOTFS}/usr/pkgs/python/2.7.5
```

The parameter will become the symlink target exactly as specified, so you have to use something that is *already* relative to the symlink's location.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that if I have another link on the way 
 like `/usr/pkgs/python/2.7.5/lib/some_link` then it will fail because it already exists in the "regular env", meaning that path already points to `/usr/pkgs/python2/2.7.5a/lib/some_link`.  So `ln -s aaa ${SINGULARITY_ROOTFS}/usr/pkgs/python/2.7.5/lib/some_link` will fail. Is there a better solution?